# How to correctly replace data in text files based on input

Tags: python, external-data-source

I have the following problem. Im trying to replace the name based on the input of gender. If anyone could help improve my code it would be really appreciated.

The text file(duedate.txt):

> User: Tommy
>
> Gender: Male
>
> Date due: 2020-02-18

The code I have so far is:

```
with open f = ('duedate.txt).read()
    z = input("Please select gender to change) 
    zz = input("Please select new name")
    if z == 'female' 
       line.startswith('User'): 
       field, value = line.split(:) 
       value = zz
       print (zz)
```

I know the code isn't 100% right but the output, if Jessica was chosen as the name, should be:

> User: Jessica
>
> Gender: Female
>
> Date due: 2020-02-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Code explanation is given in the comments:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the text file into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('duedate.txt', sep = "\n",header=None)

# Do dataframe manipulations
df[['Variable','Value']] = df[0].str.split(':',expand=True)
del df[0]

# Collect inputs from user:
z = input("Please select gender to change")
zz = input("Please select new name")

# modify dataframe based on user inputs
df.loc[0,"Value"]=zz
df.loc[1,"Value"]=z

#Construct output column
df["Output"] = df["Variable"] + ": " + df["Value"] + "\n"

# Save the file back to disk
np.savetxt(r'duedate.txt', df["Output"].values,fmt='%s')
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions! As soon as im back at my PC I'm going to give them a go. Thank you@alec and thank you @Karthick

Comment: Hey @Karthick. Can I please ask you a quick question... Ive typed the code out exactly but im getting an error saying: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: @NoobDev88 You have to install pandas package using the pip command in your python environment as "pip install pandas". You can refer to the docs here: https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Comment: Thank you so much @Karthic it works perfectly... Just one more question. If I have more than one user and a line sepperates the two. Its leaving "nan" between the lines... Any idea how to remove this?

Comment: @NoobDev88 Could you re-edit the question to show a sample of the input?

Comment: I was able to fix it... Was a problem on my side with new lines. Last question is it possible to only edit a second user without changing the first